# Generating Laravel Password using php

Tags: php, laravel

I am using PHP to generate a laravel hash password & insert it into the database using mysql query for my laravel application.
I am using `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` algorithm for password generation. Password is generated successfully , but when I go to my laravel application & login with that password, I am unable to login. It gives an error.

Here is the code to generate the password:

```
$password = password_hash($databaseData['DB_PASSWORD'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 10]);
```

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: Hey You want to generate password in Bcrypt   ?

Comment: Please always include error messages if you have one when asking questions. If you look in your DB is the hash that was generated the same as what is stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From version 5.0, Laravel uses the function `bcrypt()` to hash passwords, you should use this.

You can call the `make` method through the `Hash` facade like so:

```
Hash::make('myPassword');
```

Or choose to use the normal `bcrypt()` function like so:

```
bcrypt('myPassword');
```

You can then verify the password like this:

```
if (Hash::check('passwordInput', $hash)) {
    // password matched hash
}
```

There's more information about hashing in Laravel 5.7 [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/hashing).